# Angular - Primeng datatable sort icon missing after tomcat deployment

Tags: angular, font-awesome, primeng-datatable

I am trying to deploy my all working angular code in Tomcat. Everything works good except the sort icons are missing in the primeng datatable. Other font awesome icons are coming up well.

In the chrome console,

```
 Failed to decode downloaded font: <URL>
 Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:8080/ccm/fontawesome-webfont.af7ae505a9eed503f8b8
 Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:8080/ccm/fontawesome-webfont.fee66e712a8a08eef580

 OTS parsing error: Failed to convert WOFF 2.0 font to SFNT
 OTS parsing error: incorrect file size in WOFF header
 OTS parsing error: incorrect entrySelector for table directory`
```

[image]

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to a version of font-awesome package that I had installed earlier. I removed it from the app.module.ts, package.json, angular-cli.json and the built the application again to find the problem resolved.